How to compare case class instances for inequality?
Say I have this case class:
case class TestCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int)

I want to be able to compare its instances for inequality (operators: <, >, <=, >=) field by field like so:
val a = TestCaseClass(1,1)
val b = TestCaseClass(1,2)
println(a < b) // should print "true"

Is there a library that does this?

In Scala 2.13+, the standard library has everything you need:
// Needed to have < or > working if an implicit Ordering is in scope
import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered

case class TestCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int)

// Ordering on a then b
// More complex logic can be implemented 
implicit val ord: Ordering[TestCaseClass] = 
  Ordering.by[TestCaseClass, Int](_.a)
    .orElse(Ordering.by[TestCaseClass,Int](_.b))

val a = TestCaseClass(1,1)
val b = TestCaseClass(1,2)
println(a < b) // prints "true"

If you're looking for a more generic definition for any case class as if it was a tuple, see stefanobaghino's answer.

Which version of Scala is this? I am using 2.12.14

In my case I don't have the "orElse" part.

It's Scala 2.13+. I think you may be able to use thenComparing in 2.12 for a similar result but it's Java's interface not Scala.

stefanobaghino gave a very succinct solution

Scala 2
If by any chance all you need to do is to compare case classes "as if they were tuples", you can also do the following in both Scala 2.12 and Scala 2.13:
import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered

case class TestCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int)
 
implicit val ord: Ordering[TestCaseClass] = 
  Ordering.by(TestCaseClass.unapply)

val a = TestCaseClass(1,1)
val b = TestCaseClass(1,2)
println(a < b) // prints "true"

The unapply method makes an extractor object and is synthesized by the compiler on all case classes to allow you destructuring them in match expressions.
You can play around with this code here on Scastie.
Scala 3
You can do the same as follows:
import math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered

case class TestCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int)
 
implicit val ord: Ordering[TestCaseClass] = 
  Ordering.by(Tuple.fromProductTyped)

val a = TestCaseClass(1,1)
val b = TestCaseClass(1,2)
println(a < b) // prints "true"

You can play around with this other example here on Scastie.

Yep, this is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!

In my case I didn't have the orElse method in the Ordering class. This is what worked:
import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered

case class TestCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int, c: String)

implicit object AllFieldsOrdering extends Ordering[TestCaseClass] {
  def compare(a: TestCaseClass, b: TestCaseClass): Int = {
    val aRes = a.a.compare(b.a)
    if (aRes != 0) return aRes
    val bRes = a.b.compare(b.b)
    if (bRes != 0) return bRes
    val cRes = a.c.compare(b.c)
    return cRes
  }
}

val a = TestCaseClass(1,1, "1")
val b = TestCaseClass(1,2, "3")

println(a < b)

